# Lualatex get unicode glyph by name

Tags: luatex

I am currently using `XeTeX` as my engine, but due to it not supporting emoji I am trying to switch to LuaTeX. I have some fontawesome icons in my document specified by name (eg. `\fontawesome envelope`, where `\fontawesome` is a fontspec font family - which produces an envelope icon). I cannot get this to work with LuaTeX (it writes out "ENVELOPE" literally), and would like to ask for your support.

I know I can use character codes directly, but it would be a big annoyance over the current system. Is there a way for LuaTeX to understand unicode symbol names?

Comment: sorry but where does this \fontawesome envelope work?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the "envelope" is only a icon, showing a business envelope (for postal mail). `\fontawesome{envelope}` apparently places that icon, in XeTeX. I say "apparently" because I do not use XeTeX.

Comment: @rallg but the op doesn't use braces around envelope, and that is quite a difference.

Comment: @Aonodensetsu why not just use the [fontawesome5](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) package? It works fine with luatex (as well as pdftex and xetex) and you can call either `\faEnvelope` or `\faIcon{envelope}` to get an envelope symbol

Comment: The fontawesome package does not include all glyphs I am using, if there is a way to provide a newer fontawesome ttf to the fontawesome package this would be a valid solution (without installing to system fonts*)

Comment: you could read the documentation of the fontawesome5 package. It has a section about updates.

Comment: No idea how I missed it when it's right under the pro section but it does not work for the pro icons, ended up installing to system fonts which I didn't want to do